# How to get i Daily event participation rate In Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the event participation rate of members on a daily basis. There are 2 tables in total.
The TB_MBR table has MBR_NO (member number), JOIN_DT (join date), SSMB_DT (withdrawal date), and ST_CD (member status) columns.

The TB_EVT table has EVT_DT (event date) and MBR_NO (participation member number) columns.
At this time, we want to query the event participation rate by date.
For example, if you search from March 1, 2023 to March 6, 2023, it should come out in the following way.

[image]

At first, I thought I could simply divide by the total number of members at the current time, but then there is an error that the participation rate gradually decreases as the number of members increases every day.
So, it seems that we need to find the number of members for that day according to the search base date.

For example, if I want to retrieve data from March 1, 2023 to March 6, 2023,
The number of members participating on March 1, 2023 must be divided by the total number of members as of March 1, 2023. Then, JOIN_DT must be before March 1, 2023, and SSMB_DT must be NULL or after March 1, 2023. ST_CD column should be 'Normal'.
I'm using an oracle query and I've been struggling for days to get the data I want to output, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
with tb_ev_dt as (
select evt_dt, count(*) n_mmbr
from tb_evt
group by evt_d
)
,tbt as (
select evt_dt, n_mmbr,
  (select count(*) from tb_mbr m 
   where t.evt_dt >=m.join_dt and t.evt_dt<ssmb_dt) tot_mmbr
from from tb_evt_dt t
)
select evt_dt, n_mmbr, tot_mmbr, n_mmbr/decode(tot_mmbr,0,null,tot_mmbr) mmbr_rate
from tbt
order by evt_dt
;
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts! I got the result by modifying it as follows. The value of tot_mmbr cannot be null, but there are several. how do i fix it?             >>>>                        
          with tb_evt_dt as (
select clg_dt, count(*) n_mmbr
from tb_clg_applc_itm
group by clg_dt
)
,tbt as (
select clg_dt, n_mmbr,
  (select count(*) from tb_mbr_info m 
   where t.clg_dt >=m.join_dt and t.clg_dt<ssmb_dt) tot_mmbr
from tb_evt_dt t
)
select clg_dt, n_mmbr, tot_mmbr, n_mmbr/decode(tot_mmbr,0,null,tot_mmbr) mmbr_rate
from tbt
order by clg_dt desc